# OTRS Email attachments not visible

Tags: otrs

I've got an OTRS server running, fully functional. The only problem is that the ticket attachments can only be viewed in the web interface, and not in the emails. I always have to open the ticket in the browser first, before I can view attached images and so on.
In the web interface, everything displays fine.

Does this have to do with the /opt/otrs/bin/otrs.ArticleStorageSwitch.pl FS to DB?
Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 1):

There is as SYSconfig function for this

```
Ticket -> Frontend::Agent::Ticket::ArticleAttachmentModule
```

There should be two modules.
In the

```
Framework -> Core::Web::AttachmentDownloadType
```

You can select what module to use.

This is default set to attachment, but when it is set to inline it doesn't download the attachment but it only shows them inline.